# How to get all Keys/Parameters/Attributes from a File Object of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, object

I'm getting the keys from a File Object on JavaScript, but I don't know why the Objects methods aren't working.

I have tried Object.keys() and Object.getOwnPropertyNames(). Why those methods don't work?

Here's the example:

```
        var obj = {name:'my_name',id:1,value:'my_val'}
        const file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];

        console.log('Object.keys(file)',Object.keys(file));
        //Array []
        console.log('Object.keys(obj)',Object.keys(obj));
        //Array [3]
        console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames(file)',Object.getOwnPropertyNames(file));
        //Array []
        console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)',Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
        //Array [3]
        console.log('file.name',file.name);
        //name.type
        console.log('obj.name',obj.name);
        //my_name
        console.log('Object',file);
        //File {...}
        console.log('Object',obj);
        //Object {...}
        console.log('type',typeof file);
        //object
        console.log('type',typeof obj);
        //object
```

Answer (score 3):

`Object.keys()` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` only return own properties whether they are enumerable or not. In this case, the properties you are trying to get, belong to its `prototype`. So these methods won't work.

You can still get its attributes by doing something like this:

```
const attributes = [];
for (attribute in file) {
  attributes.push(attribute);
}
```